# Google sheets subtract cells N columns and rows apart

Tags: google-sheets, subtraction

how can I subtract cells **A2** from **A1** without directly using cell addresses? I would like to write **A2** as a cell **-1 column away** and **A1** as a cell **-1 column away and -1 row away**.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYahf.png)

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [offset](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) function on sheets.

An example formula based on your example would be: `=(OFFSET(B2,0,-1)-OFFSET(B2,-1,-1))`

[image: Example Sheet and Result]

Comment: Yes, but i still have to point to "B2". Is it possible to additionally save B2 as the current cell? In my case, I cannot point to any cell directly (I forgot to write it in the question)

Comment: In that case you can make use of reference for row,colum as number by using the Address function (Replace the cell reference with Address to locate their cell. Example Address(1,1) points to A1. Here's more information about it: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308. If that won't apply to what you're trying to implement then there's no other way to reference cell location other than by cell name or row/column numbers.

Comment: There really is no way of pointing to THIS cell? Something like this(), or current()

Comment: No straightforward function as such. LIke what I mentioned, you can utilize the address function and combine it with Row numbers and Column. =address(row(),Column()) indicates the current cell where the formula is, you can iterate by adding or subtracting from it. (+ or -), example =address(row()-1,Column())

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function along with [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en), [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) and [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en)

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Indirect with [RC notation](https://dsernst.com/2015/05/29/spreadsheet-relative-cell-references/) as below:

=indirect("RC[-1]",false)-indirect("R[-1]C[-1]",false)

[image]